# How to terminate code upon RuntimeWarning

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am using scipy.optimize.fsolve to solve two nonlinear equations. When the boundary conditions cannot be satisfied, I would like to program to terminate and print a warning message. I have set the maximum number of iterations such that `maxfev = 20`

```
sol = fsolve(f, [1e-6,1e-6], xtol=1e-6, maxfev=20, full_output=False, col_deriv=True)
```

How can I terminate the programm when I get the following RuntimeWarning?

> RuntimeWarning: The number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 20.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [warnings.simplefilter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) for instance.

Here an example that don't stop with `DeprecationWarning`, but stop with `RuntimeWarning`

```
def fn():
    warnings.warn('deprecation', DeprecationWarning)
    print('running after deprecation warning')
    warnings.warn('runtime', RuntimeWarning)
    print('running after runtime warning')
fn() # ends normally

warnings.simplefilter('error', RuntimeWarning)
fn() # raises an error on RuntimeWarning
```